# How do I check the user has entered two or more words in a single string?

Tags: python, string, input, split

My function takes a string, and as long as the string has two names in it, such as "John Smith", the program runs OK.

My issue occurs when the user enters 1 or less names in their input.

```
user_input = input("Enter your name: ")

name = user_input.split()

print(name[0])
print(name[1])
```

Ideally, it would check that the user has entered a string of just two names, but it doesn't really matter.

I don't know the required checks in Python; if it was Java, it would be a different story.

Comment: `len(name)` should give you the number of words the user entered. Combine that with an `if` condition and you have a word-count check.

Comment: Since you know how to do it in java, what speaks against doing it exactly the same way (and googling how to do those exact same things)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `len()` or `try/except` as in:

```
user_input = input("Enter your name: ")
if len(user_input.split()) > 1:
    print("At least two words.")
else:
    print("Only one word")
```

Or

```
user_input = input("Enter your name: ")
try:
    user_input.split()[1]
    print("At least two words.")
except IndexError:
    print("Only one word")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
user_input = input("Enter your name: ")

name = user_input.split()

for x in names:
    print(x)
```